# Check if a certain character is followed by another character?

Tags: c#, for-loop, boolean

How can I check if a certain character is followed by another character in a string?

I want to check if every 'A' in a string is followed by at least one 'B'. The 'B' doesn't have to directly follow it and there doesn't have to be an even number of A's and B's.

For example:

AAZZBB = true

AAAXXXXYB = true

BBYYYXXXAXX = false

YYYBABYYYXXXAXX = false

Here's code I worked on but it keeps returning true:

```
 public bool BalancedAB(string str)
        {
            int endPos = str.Length - 1;
            for (int pos = 0; pos <= endPos; pos++)
            {
                if (str[pos] == 'A')
                {
                    if (pos < endPos)
                    {
                        char next = str[pos + 1];

                        if (next == 'B')
                        {
                            pos++;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What does return at this case : `AZZBB`?

Comment: `if (str.LastIndexOf("A") != -1 && str.IndexOf("B", str.LastIndexOf("A")) > -1) `

Comment: This is a pretty poor way to structure the code.   Use of `continue` generally emits a bad code smell and there are very few cases in history where `continue` should be used.   It does not surprise me that it is returning `true` erroneously.  if you arrive at an `A` and the very next character is not `B` and it's not at the end of the string then it will return true.

Answer (score 3):

You can just check if the last index of one character is greater than the last index of the other

```
(myString.IndexOf('A') > -1) && (myString.LastIndexOf('A') < myString.LastIndexOf('B'))
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: Edge case. `string myString = "B";` I think this not clear in question

Comment: @L.B - Good spot, I've added an extra check for the first character for this case

Answer (score 0):

This code has worked on your test cases:

```
bool HasABPairs(string word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == 'A')
        {
            bool hasEquivalentB = false;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < word.Length; j++)
            {
                if (word[j] == 'B')
                {
                    hasEquivalentB = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!hasEquivalentB)
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I think there's probably a solution that isn't O(n²), but this solves the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your function as in example shown below:

```
public static bool BalancedAB(string str)
{
    int endPos = str.Length - 1;
    for (int pos = 0; pos <= endPos; pos++)
    {
        if (str[pos] == 'A')
        {
            bool retValue = false;
            while (pos < endPos)
            {
                if (str[pos + 1] != 'B') { pos++; }
                else
                {
                    retValue = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!retValue) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```